# how do i fix the KeyError issue im having

Tags: python, keyerror

**I'm getting a keyerror for 'Item' and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. it's for the line. item = get_item(state) I'm a noob to coding and I've spent the last 5 hours and can not fix the issue.**

***NOT IMPORTANT***
*Scenario
You work for a small company that creates text-based games. You recently pitched your design ideas for a text-based adventure game to your team. Your team was impressed by all of your designs, and would like you to develop the game! You will be able to use the map and the pseudocode or flowcharts from your designs to help you develop the code for the game. In your code, you have been asked to include clear naming conventions for functions, variables, and so on, along with in-line comments. Not only will these help you keep track as you develop, but they will help your team read and understand your code. This will make it easier to adapt for other games in the future.
Recall that the game requires players to type in a command line prompt to move through the different rooms and get items from each room. The goal of the game is for the player to get all of the items before encountering the room that contains the villain. Each step of the game will require a text output to let the player know where they are in the game, and an option of whether or not to obtain the item in each room.*

```
rooms = {
'Master Bedroom': {'South': 'Kitchen', 'North': 'Toy Room', 'East': 'Garage', 'West': 'Closet'},
'Kitchen': {'North': 'Master Bedroom', 'East': 'Bathroom', 'West': 'Backyard', 'Item': 'Cell Phone'},
'Gun Room': {'South': 'Closet', 'East': 'Toy room', 'Item': 'Pistol'},
'Backyard': {'East': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'ZOMBIE'},
'Garage': {'West': 'Master Bedroom', 'South': 'Bath Room', 'Item': 'Body Armor'},
'Toy Room': {'South': 'Master Bedroom', 'West': 'Gun Room', 'Item': 'Baseball Bat'},
'Closet': {'East': 'Master Bedroom', 'North': 'Gun Room', 'Item': 'Flashlight'},
'Bathroom': {'North': 'Garage', 'West': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'Bandages'},
}

state = 'Master Bedroom'
def get_new_state(state, direction):
    new_state = state
    for i in rooms:
        if i == state:
            if direction in rooms[i]:
                new_state=rooms[i][direction]

    return new_state
def get_item(state):
    return rooms[state]['Item']
def show_instructions():
    print('ZOMBIE run Adventure Game')
    print('Collect 6 items to win the game, or be eaten by a ZONBIE.')
    print('Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West')
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'Item_name'")
    print("type quit to end the game")
show_instructions() #calling Function
Inventory = []

while (1):
    print('You are in ', state) #printing state
    print('Inventory:', Inventory) #printing inventory
    item = get_item(state) #calling get_item function
    print('You see a ', item) #print
    print('--------------------')
    if item == 'ZOMBIE':
        print('NOM NOM...GAME OVER!')
        exit(0)
    
    direction = input('Enter your move:')
    if direction == 'go East' or direction == 'go West' or direction == 'go North' or direction == 'go South': #if
        direction = direction[3:]
        new_state = get_new_state(state, direction) #calling function
        if new_state == state: #if
            print('The room has wall in that direction enter other direction!')
        else:
            state = new_state
    elif direction == str('get ' + item):
        if item in inventory:
            print('Item already taken go to another room!!')
        else:
            inventory.append(item)
    else:
        print('Invalid direction!')
    
    if len(Inventory) == 6:
        print('Congratulations! You have collected all items and defeated the ZOMBIE!')
        exit(0)

stop = "go"

while stop != 'quit':
    show_instructions()
    user_input = input("what would you like to do?")
    if user_input == 'quit':
        break
```

Comment: What inputs trigger this error?

Comment: Could you also fix the indentation on your code?

Comment: The code will not work with this line `print('--------------------')if item`.

Comment: Broken the indentation is all jacked up from how i had to enter it into the stack it looks diffrenet in my IDE

Comment: @ydocsgarage: Try re-pasting with indentation. Right now, it is very hard to decipher.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be the fact that there is no item in the master bedroom. Hence it throws a `KeyError`. You just need to add an `'Item'` value to the `rooms['Master Bedroom']`

Edit: The context seems to be that the `Master Bedroom` has no item. So it would be better if you just added a state validation:

```
def get_item(state):
    if state!='Master Bedroom':
        return ' a'+rooms[state]['Item']
    else:
        return 'Nothing'
```

And just for the text to make sense:

```
print('You see', item) #print
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid KeyError, a useful method of dicts is `get`.

```
>>>rooms.get('item')
>>>
```

you can give a default value as 2nd argument in case the key does not exist:

```
>>>rooms.get('item', 'this room does not exist')
>>>'this room does not exist'
```

or in case of nested dicts

```
>>>rooms = {'kitchen': {'items': ['sink', 'oven']}}
>>>rooms.get('kitchen').get('items')
>>>['sink', 'oven']
```